# Remove Create and Edit... for a Many2many_tags field

Tags: python, openerp-7, odoo

I have a field Taxes in the sales module. I have only one kind of tax ie, Vat 20%. So I shouldn't allow users to create more taxes. For that I need to disable the Create and Edit button for Many2many_tags field. I wont give access rights for users to create new taxes from accounting module,

Is there any way I can do that.
The sale.py files for this field is

```
'tax_id': fields.many2many('account.tax', 'sale_order_tax', 'order_line_id', 'tax_id', 'Taxes', readonly=True, required=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}),
```

and the sale_view.xml file is

```
<field name="tax_id" widget = "many2many_tags" domain="[('parent_id','=',False),('type_tax_use','&lt;&gt;','purchase')]">
```

If it is not possible to remove the Create or Edit... is there any way to make use of function Default to set a default value for many2many_tags field. ??

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<field name="field_name"
    widget="many2many_tags"
    options="{'no_create_edit': True}"/>
```

refer this if you want more.

```
http://ludwiktrammer.github.io/odoo/form-widgets-many2many-fields-options-odoo.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the **web_m2x_options** module and add in our project addons and give the set of instruction(you can know those instruction in side the addons from Read me file ) where you want to remove the Create and Edit Option.